# SCons carshed when option is given value containing a colon

Tags: scons

On Windows, when I pass an argument to SCons (added using AddOption) that contains ':', Scons exits with error code 2 and doesn't compile. All steps prior to compilation are executed.

```
scons --test_option="abc:" # Fails
scons --test_option="abc" # Works
```

It doesn't work even when the option itself is unused.

Colon is passed in the first place to provide full path. However it seems not to be path related.

Version: 2.2

Comment: Have you tried to see if there's an exception being thrown? You can use the standard Python try/except exception handling and wrap pertinent parts of your SCons scripts in try blocks.

Comment: Thanks. I found the problem. It was in the specific scons script and not in the framework.